# Using Selenium 2 with Webforms in C# - Are there any helper methods to simplify common tasks?

Tags: c#, selenium, webforms

My company is using Selenium 2 to automate testing with Webforms (as well as MVC).  For webforms, we end up using xpath all over the place for the simplest of tasks, since the control id's are changed.  We often have things like this:

```
driver.clickByXPath("//input[contains(@id,'radioManual')]");
driver.sendKeysByXPath("//input[contains(@id, 'txtName')]", value, true);
driver.sendKeysByXPath("//table[@id='add-external-form']/tbody/tr/td[1]/input", value);
```

We've gotten used to xpath by now, but the code is still tedious to write.  Are there any wrapper methods that are available to simplify common tasks like:

- Selecting a Radiobutton
- Select an option from a DropDownList
- Entering text into a textbox
- Clicking a link
- Checking a checkbox

Comment: I'm not sure what you could do to make this easier, really.  Those three methods all operate on separate controls.  You might be able to reduce code duplication by storing the path strings in a common location, so you don't have to duplicate them between tests.  But your UI is custom - helper methods wouldn't do much to help you with that, unless they could somehow auto-generate all the xpath for you.

Comment: Have you looked at using Selenium WebDriver instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own extensions. It is not very difficult. For example enter text in textbox:

```
public static IWebElelemt SetTextBoxValue(this IWebElement element, string value)
{
    element.SendKeys(value);
    return element;
}
```

and use it like:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("some id")).SetTextBoxValue("Hello");
```

or extension to WebDriver:

```
public static IWebElelemt SetTextBoxValue(this IWebDriver driver,string id, string value)
{
    var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
    element.SendKeys(value);
    return element;
}
```

Or extension to return parent element:

```
public static IWebElement GetParent(this IWebElement element)
{
   return element.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
}
```

This are only few examples, also you can create extensions that perform some actions by executing JavaScript. For example:

```
public static JavaScriptExecutor Script(this IWebDriver driver)
{
   return driver as JavaScriptExecutor;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var count = driver.Script().ExecuteScript("return $('some selector').length;").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell those are wrapped methods.  Selenium doesn't have clickByXPath or sendKeysByXpath method in them.  I am guessing that there is some custom extensions to the IWebDriver interface that has been done by your company already to reduce the amount of code.

Also you can't just say click my_radio_button because you have to pass in a selector for Selenium to find the specific radio button you are looking for.  Same with just about anything else you do with selenium it has to have some way to traverse the DOM and know what it's looking for to do an action on.

Based on your edits there are a few thing that I have done to make selecting options and inputting text much easier.

First I usually capture all text input fields into a `List<IWebElement>` then I remove any that aren't displayed since webdriver can't interact with hidden fields.  I then have a random character generator that fills my fields with data for me.

Here's an example:

```
    public void InputValidText(List<IWebElement> inputList)
    {
        foreach (IWebElement element in inputList)
        {
            if (element.Displayed)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("type") == "checkbox")
                {
                    if (!element.Selected)
                    {
                        element.Click();
                    }
                }
                else if (element.TagName == "select")
                {
                    if (element.GetAttribute("id") != "CreditCardYearExp")
                    {
                        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
                        int options = element.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count();
                        select.SelectByIndex(new Random().Next(1, options - 1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
                        int options = element.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count();
                        select.SelectByIndex(new Random().Next(3, options - 1));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string inputToValidate = element.GetAttribute("id").ToString();
                        element.Clear();
                        if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(NameInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.GeneralLongTextInput);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(PostalCodeInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.PostalCode);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(PhoneNumberInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.LongPhoneNumber);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(EmailInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.NewEmail);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(AddressInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.GeneralAddress);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(PasswordInputValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.NewPassword);
                        }
                        else if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextAreaValidation)).Contains(inputToValidate))
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.GeneralTextAreaInput);
                        }
                        else if (inputToValidate == "CreditCardTextBox")
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.CreditCard);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            element.SendKeys(ValidContent.GeneralShortTextInput);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```